# Android sequential execution of functions

Tags: android, networking, sequence

I know Android UI is not really meant for executing functions and waiting for them to finish, however, I think there are use cases were it is required, like networking.

My problem is, I want to run a series of network operations that rely on each other and take a bit more time than the split second it takes to the next execution, so some waiting is in order:

1. Start hotspot
2. Get network interfaces and IP
3. Start socket

Initially I tested that all is working using buttons, then it waited between my button presses. But now I'd like to automatize it. I googled but all I found are solutions with Async task, which is deprecated. I tried with threads and join, but that usually causes weird crashes in the runnable, and it is not very elegant. I wonder if there is another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you can do with SDK it's use `Executors` to run your work in background sequentially

```
        val newSingleThreadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        newSingleThreadExecutor.execute {
            // 1...
        }
        newSingleThreadExecutor.execute {
            // 2...
        }
```

But if you want to touch the UI from background should create handler check if view's not null

```
        val handler = Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!)
        newSingleThreadExecutor.execute {
            handler.post {
                view?.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I worked with SingleThreadExecutors before, but didn't think of it. I adjusted the code for java: Executor steps = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        steps.execute(this::fkt1);        steps.execute(this::fkt2);...

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          startHotspot();
          getNetworkInterfaceAndIP();
          startSocket();
         }
       }, 300);
```

Comment: Isn't that just executing all three like normally, except for a 300ms delay (but not for each, right)?

Comment: Well, the 300 ms is changeable, and it's different since you put it in a handler.postDelayer, this is the same as running them in a thread.

Comment: Yes, but I mean, I want to run fun1, wait that it finishes, fun2, wait... etc. Your handler just waits, fun1, fun2, fun3, right? Of course I can make 3 handlers, but the executor works just as I wanted.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to run them all in the background, not having 1 function wait for the other, sorry, in that case my answer is irrelevant]